# Bitbucket pipeline - Unable to deploy dist folder to my server

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a wordpress theme to server through bitbucket pipeline, it is working fine but it's not deploying **dist** folder. I think it's because I have **dist** folder added in my .gitignore file

Here's my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

```
    - step:

        name: 'Deployment to Production'

        image: node:10.16.2

        deployment: production

        trigger: 'manual'

        script:

          - npm install

          - npm test

          - yarn

          - yarn build:production

          - apt-get update

          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp

          - git ftp push --insecure --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS ftpes://ftp.mydomain.dev/public_html/wp-content/themes/cule --all
```

am i missing anything? should I remove dist folder from my .gitignore file?

Here's my .gitignore file

**.gitignore**

```
.cache-loader
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
resources/assets/config-local.json
node_modules
dist
```

Answer (score 1):

`git-ftp` will push all the untracked files and folders listed in the `.git-ftp-include` file. This is documented [here](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#syncing-untracked-files).

At the bare minimum, your repository could be configured to *always* push the `dist` folder by adding a file named `.git-ftp-include` at the repository root with the following content:

```
!dist/
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#syncing-untracked-files) enlists more options to conditionally update the `dist` folder.